# What is the maximum number of pings a message in chat can contain before people are not notified?

Tags: support, chat, ping

I've noticed that once there are a certain amount of @pings in a chat message, the users who are mentioned don't actually get notified.

For instance, we sometimes have the bot [ping lots of people](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45555322#45555322) for a Codenames game. The linked message consists of this, only:

> @BusinessCat @Rubio @Forklift @JohnDvorak @MorganG @Deusovi @You @ffao @boboquack @thecoder16 @ConorO'Brien @Mithrandir @GarethMcCaughan @notjagan @dcfyj @micsthepick @Wen1now @cairdcoinheringaahing @Tumbler41 @Scrooble

I'm the twelfth ping in that message. I was in the room at the time - the message showed with the ping highlighted, like usual, but there was no ping sound and no circle appearing on my avatar. I've noticed this in the past as well, for mass-pings.

How many pings does it take for pings to be not counted as pings? Is it just a number or does it matter what percentage of the message is the pings? Is it *all* the users who won't get pinged, or just the ones past the threshold? Basically... what are the rules for when the ping won't actually notify the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had the [same question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43223123#43223123) over on [the Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) awhile back and [tested this for science](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43223144#43223144). It turns out that the [first 10 people](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43223202#43223202) will be pinged with a notification, however everyone afterwards will only have the message highlighted in chat, but receive no notification. Interestingly enough, [duplicate pings](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43223195#43223195) (pinging the same person multiple times in the same message) count towards the cap, though they won't receive multiple notifications.